# How to order data frame by a partial string (or first word)

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I'm self-learning basic operations.

I would like to yield the following:

```
County   Population
ACounty, Alabama   106242
BCounty, Alabama   362845
ACounty, Texas   242342
BCounty, Texas   293729
```

I've tried:

```
df<-df %>% arrange(County)
view(df)
```

Which ends up as:

```
County   Population
ACounty, Alabama   106242
ACounty, Texas   242342
BCounty, Alabama   362845
BCounty, Texas   293729
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide County and States and `arrange` data based on State.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(County, c('County', 'State'), sep = ",\\s*") %>%
  arrange(State) %>%
  unite(County, County, State, sep = ",")
```

---

In base R, you can keep only the state information by removing everything till comma and use `order` to arrange data by state.

```
df[order(sub('.*,', '', df$County)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without splitting or uniting

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    arrange(str_remove(County, ",.*"))
#            County Population
#1 ACounty, Alabama     106242
#2   ACounty, Texas     242342
#3 BCounty, Alabama     362845
#4   BCounty, Texas     293729
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(County = c("ACounty, Alabama", "BCounty, Alabama", 
"ACounty, Texas", "BCounty, Texas"), Population = c(106242L, 
362845L, 242342L, 293729L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```